# Docker toolbox cannot allocate memory

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to get Docker running a container locally on my mac that I've been working on in the cloud. I did the docker commit/save/load find. But when I got to run it locally after I installed docker toolbox I get this error

```
docker logs es-loaded-with-data
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000006c5330000, 4207738880, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
Starting elasticsearch: #
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 4207738880 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid16.log

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000006c5330000, 4207738880, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
Starting elasticsearch: #
```

If I do `docker info`
then I get

> Total Memory: 1.956 GiB

clearly 2 Gb isn't enough. How do I increase it so my container will run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker on Mac OS runs inside a virtualbox VM with either docker-machine (or older boot2docker). I am not sure if docker-machine supports modifying the VM RAM directly, but you can probably just start the `VirtualBox.app` and modify the amount of VM Memory directly. Restart the VM et voilá.

Comment: Wow I messed around with config files etc and it turns out I could just use the GUI... thank you ZeissS. Sometimes another set of eyes helps

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the docker service solved the problem for me.

Comment: That helped me too ... may be because the host memory was already occupied by the already running docker containers and restarting docker service killed them